# Is this question seeking personal advice on topic?

Tags: discussion

[How do I get started again when I've lost heart?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117900/how-do-i-get-started-again-when-ive-lost-heart)

The OP seems to have had a rough time; I can sympathize with that, but "*does anybody have any tips on how to move past great loss.... if anybody has had a heart-injury (solar-plexus blow) knock them off-track... tell me your story of how you got back on track*" seems a bit off-topic to me.

Yet, the question seems to be well-received based on the number of upvotes the question has gathered, the number of upvoted answers posted under the question by prominent members of the community, and the fact that there is not even a single close-vote on the question at this time.

On the other hand, maybe I don't understand what this site is about any more. Is this the sort of content that we wish to encourage?

Comment: The question ended up on the HNQ which is most likely why had a sharp increase in votes and views. It has been pulled as of now.

Comment: I consider it completely off-topic for several reasons, but since several notable 'heavyweights' on this site have contributed answers it would be probably be futile to try to get it closed.

Comment: @PiedPiper you don't get heavyweight by not answering questions...

Comment: @user1079505 I’m #4 all time rep and I don’t take the time to answer questions I don’t think are good fits or have interesting answers. Answering a modest amount of questions very well and over a long period of time is effective.